# Aggregate multiple embedded neo4j graph into one neo4j instance

Tags: aggregate, neo4j, graph-databases

I'm using a Neo4j java embedded graph database to store each simulation results on each node of a computer grid. Now to ask good question to this data, i need to aggregate this huge amount of multiple embedded graph object into one unique central neo4j object (or server).

Do you have some in head some internet ressources which explain this ? Do you have some experience to share with me on this use case ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Mmh,

that depends on the layout of your merge. IS it do go into different subgraphs, time-ordered or otherwise? There is no utility per se, since the merge semantics are not generic. Ask on http://groups.google.com/group/neo4j/ for others who might have good algos for this.

Comment: It's different subgraph i think, but it's not for backup only, we want to query data with time based or space based agregation between all of subgraph collected.